# I am looking to add Messenger support to my app, but I do not require facebook login button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Our app aims to seamlessly create tickets from Facebook Messenger interactions without requiring users to log in through Facebook Login. Here's how it works:

Facebook Page Setup: We have a dedicated Facebook Page for our business or app, which serves as the point of contact for users on Messenger.

Messenger Bot: We've developed a Messenger bot using the Facebook Messenger Platform. This bot handles user interactions and can receive messages from them.

Webhook Integration: To link Messenger with our app, we've implemented a webhook. This webhook allows us to receive messages and notifications from Messenger and trigger actions in our app accordingly.

User Experience: Users can initiate a conversation with our Messenger bot directly from our Facebook Page. They can inquire about tickets, report issues, or seek assistance without needing to log in through Facebook. Our bot interacts with users and, when necessary, creates tickets or performs other relevant actions in our app based on their requests.
So for Advance access to pages_messaging I wouldn't have Login button in my app, so it can be result for the app review rejection?